# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm working on a android project in which I have to decrypt string from a file in PHP server, encryption was done using PHP.(AES 128 algorithm)

Encryption Code:

```
 function aes128Encrypt($key, $data) {
      $key = md5($key);
      return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, str_repeat("\0", 16));
    }
```

My code for getting string from URL:

```
String myUri = "http://www.example.com/lib2.php";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

String bodyHtml = "";
String xmlFile = "";
bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(bodyHtml);
xmlFile = decrypt(bodyHtml);
System.out.println(xmlFile);
```

decrypt() method:

```
public static String decrypt(String encData) throws Exception
    {
        Key key = generateKey();

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo + "/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo);

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes);

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key , ivSpec);

        //byte[] decValue = Base64.decode(encData , Base64.NO_PADDING);

        //byte[] decFin = Base64.decode(decValue, Base64.NO_PADDING);

        //byte[] decFinal = c.doFinal(decValue);

        byte[] decFinal = c.doFinal(encData.getBytes());

        String getAns = new String(decFinal, "UTF8");

        return getAns;
    }
```

In generateKey():

```
public static Key generateKey()
    {

        try {
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                    .getInstance("MD5");

            digest.update(myChar.getBytes());

            key1 = digest.digest();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(key1,algo);     
        return key;
    }
}
```

The Logcat shows below exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

at the line `c.doFinal()`

The Codes I'v commented out are also the codes I'v used to check. What is wrong with this code?. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use `MD5` for key strengthening. If the key is already cryptographically strong you are all but wasting processor cycles hashing it with md5. If the key is **not** cryptographically strong please use a proper algorithm like `Scrypt`, `Bcrypt` or `PBKDF#2` to facilitate key strengthening.

Comment: @CPUTerminator  Sure, but that won't solve this issue, will that? And also I don't have permission to change any code in PHP. So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: No it won't solve your issue. But the solution posted by Max Power will. If no padding mechanism is specified, by default php pads the message with \0 (I think) if the message isn't a multiple of the block size. Thus using AES/CBC/NoPadding should yield a message that is correct but may have additional spaces at the end. Since the message has been pre-padded by php to a appropriate size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is the way you treat the value from the PHP server as a Java `String`. The PHP `mcrypt_encrypt` function returns a *binary* string, where each byte can have any value. PHP `mcrypt_encrypt` does not use any character encoding. So using `EntityUtils.toString()` is already an error - and using `String.getBytes()` without specifying the encoding generally is as well.

You just need to use either [`getContent()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) or [`writeTo(OutputStream outstream)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to get the the binary ciphertext. If you opt for the first option, you can wrap a [`CipherInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) around it. Initialize it with the `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"` cipher and you can directly decrypt the plain text string. Beware that you may have to trim a certain number of `00` valued bytes from the result to get to the plaintext.

Comment: And also what should I do to trim and get the exact string?, I'm getting it like a corrupted one now.

Comment: A corrupted plaintext indicates that something is still a mismatch between the encryption/decryption or encoding/decoding. Note that without padding, decryption will only fail if the stream does not contain a full number of blocks. If the key or ciphertext has been altered, it will simply return garbage... Trimming is only required for `00` bytes at the end, as indicated.

Comment: But the plaintext not fully corrupted it's the same text before encryption, but its not in order, starts printing from beginning of the text ends and then again prints from beginning. I'v used like this `byte[] encData = new byte[1600]; String add = "";` `while((dummy = cis.read(encData)) != -1) { System.out.println(new String(encData , "UTF-8").trim());  add = add + (new String(encData , "UTF-8").trim()); } ` And I can't store the whole plain text in to a string , it only stores a part.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628307/issue-with-java-string-and-string-builder

Comment: @KarthikSivam looks like you already have answered your question there. There is no need to trim() each string by the way, you only need to remove (or: not decode) the last bytes valued `00` of the *entire* decrypted plaintext. Calling `trim()` for each block would remove whitespace from your plaintext (including spaces and such).

Answer (score 2):

Your chiper is expecting padding "/CBC/PKCS7Padding". This has nothing to do with encoding of messages (BASE64). Either change expected chipher on java side or encrypt with padding on php side.

Chipers are specified `algorithm/mode/padding` or `algortihm`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html for details.

Your are specifying a chiper with padding but actually do zero padding on php side,

excerpt from http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php:

```
# creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
# to keep the text confidential 
# only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
# (because of default zero padding)
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                             $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Comment: I can't change anything on PHP side, What should I change in java code , Padding? since I'v used the same AES algorithm , CBC mode used in PHP.

Comment: Please try with "AES/CBC/NoPadding"

Comment: Thank you.I'v tried using NoPadding but it gives `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length`. That means anything to do with the data read?

Comment: @NitinMisra Yes, Please check the answer I have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by avoiding reuse of cipher. each time i init it again. just initing might be enough.

```
 try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(ps, salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);

            // Build encryptor and get IV
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

            // Build decryptor
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```