# Issue with java String and String Builder

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder, trim

I'm working on a project in which I have to decrypt a xml text from PHP server and parse into java, I have decrypted the xml text by using CipherInputStream and seen xml file fully get printed, but I'm facing a weird issue while trying to store the xml text in a java string, I'm working on the code below:

```
public String decrypt(InputStream Fis){

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algo + "/CBC/NoPadding");

String add = "";

StringBuilder getAns = new StringBuilder();

c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(Fis , c);

byte[] encData = new byte[16];

int dummy;

while ((dummy = cis.read(encData)) != -1)
        {

            System.out.println(new String(encData, "UTF-8").trim()); 

                    add = (new String(encData, "UTF-8").trim());

                    getAns.append(add);


}

System.out.println(getAns); 
...
}
```

It prints the full XML text in log cat by the first println statement inside while loop, But when printing the StringBuilder `getAns`, it only prints a part of the text.

I have also tried just using String:

```
add = add + (new String(encData, "UTF-8").trim());
```

also using `ArrayList<String>` but it only prints a part of the text.

I guess this may be due to a silly mistake , but I'm struggling with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the expected and actual outputs, especially the text right around where the `getAns` input stop. Note that the contents of `add` don't include a newline, which is appended by `println`.

Comment: @chrylis   But sorry I can't post those codes, that's why I'm working on encrypting and decrypting the text.

Comment: Did you try removing the print statement and see if the StringBuilder works? Try debugging and see what content the add String has.

Comment: @dARKpRINCE  Yup I've added the print statement only after that issue.

Comment: @chrylis I'v also tried using `System.out.print()`  ,   `String myString = getAns.toString().replaceAll(" " , "");` and then `myString = getAns.toString().replaceAll("\n" , "");`

Comment: Is there any other way I can store this to string? or my code is wrong huh.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally caught the issue, It's with the `System.out.pritnln()`, It has certain limits for printing. This function can only print around 4060 characters at a time, I've found this by using `getAns.substring(10000,15000);`.

Comment: @laalto  But, In my case it prints around 4060 characters at a time. Then it may have offered 4 more kB as grace bytes for me huh? Will you please direct me to that info page where you have got this info?

Comment: Use `adb logcat -g` to get logcat params. E.g. for my primary device the payload max size is 4076 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading some bytes from the input stream inside the while condition:

```
while ((dummy = cis.read(encData)) != -1)
```

This already populates the `encData` byte array with having the correct number of read bytes in the `dummy` variable. Afterwards you again read some bytes:

```
dummy = cis.read(encData);
```

This overwrites the bytes you have read one step before. Delete that line!

Comment: Oops, sorry by mistake I'v pasted that while posting , I'v edited my post.

Comment: Does that mean, you still have the issue with the now edited code? Does that also mean, that you didn't test the code you posted? Then I must ask you to first write a simple and running program, minimized to the problem you are facing. Maybe with some test data, that we can use.

Comment: Ya still having the same issue, I've posted the code which I tested before.